# Temporary file for running a command

Tags: bash, shell, tmp

How can I run something more simpler than:

echo `date` > tmp.html && firefox tmp.html && rm tmp.html

Is it possible to get the same without creating and deleting the tmp.html?

Comment: Seeing as it apparently serves no purpose, sure: just `firefox a.html`...

Comment: could you add a little bit about the end result/functionality you're shooting for?

Comment: @jasonwryan, sorry, it's not a.html, but tmp.html in all cases.

Comment: @user3276552: changed the command. It's not for showing date on firefox. It's just for calling my attention on the browser at certain time. The idea is to pipe the output of a command to firefox (or whatever browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/tmp` is cleared on boot, so you can do this

```
date > /tmp/date.html && firefox /tmp/date.html
```

if you want to open the result of any command in a browser, add this to your shell startup script

```
function open_in_browser {
  echo $@ > /tmp/temp.html
  firefox /tmp/temp.html
}
```

and then you can call

```
$ open_in_browser `date`
```

alternatively, if you'd prefer a more secure approach with stdin and better styling, you can use this function instead

```
function stdin_to_browser {
    local tmpfile=`mktemp /tmp/command-output.XXXXX.html`
    cat - > ${tmpfile}
    sed -i -e '1{s#^#<pre>#;};${s#$#</pre>#;}' ${tmpfile}
    firefox ${tmpfile} 2> /dev/null
}
```

which would let you

```
ifconfig | stdin_to_browser
```

(this example uses @thrig's suggestion of `mktemp`)

Comment: Or consider `mktemp` to avoid potential `/tmp` security flaws...